# How to simplify this hypergeometric expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

How can I rewrite this expression in terms of a single `Hypergeometric` function? Is it possible? I think it is possible to convert this expression in such a way that the `Gamma` function disappears.

```
(Sqrt[b] Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] q0^(1/2) Gamma[5/4])/Gamma[7/4] - 
 b  r Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2), 1/4, 5/4, -((b^2 r^4)/q0^2)]
```

Comment: "a single Hypergeometric function" - I see only one, so what exactly do you mean by this?

Comment: @J.M.willbebacksoon : it is edited. I am trying to simplify this expression. I need only one term here.

Comment: I notice that the derivative of your expression has a simple form; did this come from an integral?

Comment: yes. In fact the gamma term goes from a condition on the asymptotic behavior. However, it will be more convenient if one can simplify this constant term.

Comment: Just to temper your expectations: what you want isn't always possible. As a more elementary example, look at the case of [$\operatorname{arcsec}$](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ArcSec/26/01/01/), which has [a simpler integral expression](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ArcSec/07/01/01/0002/).